# Why does the last character of my ETag disappear?

Tags: gzip, etag, dropwizard

I'm currently implementing a solution for ETags in an Dropwizard-based application. But the GZip filter (I assume) eats the last character from the ETag.

For example, I set the ETag `01234` and the client sees `0123-gzip`.

Does anybody have a clue?